# Is it possible to get record data and SObject metadata in a single API call?

Tags: rest-api, dynamic-soql, custom

We're trying to handle custom fields for things like Tasks. Is there any best practice for doing things dynamically? We've made a webapp that lets users from various organizations connect. So it's not just one organization that we're looking at.

The form should allow users to create a new Task, including specifying values for all of the custom fields. I'd like to do this in as few API calls as possible too.

I know that when looking up an object, we get back all of the custom fields. I also know about the describe call that will give me the information on all of the SObjects. However, that's 2 API calls right there. Is there a better way of doing this sort of thing?

I'm looking for a way to grab the SObject but also grab its description at the same time.

Similarly, if certain profiles have permissions, is there a way to access this information in 1 API call as well?

Comment: By "grab the SObject but also grab its description at the same time", do you mean, get the record data, and the SObject metadata at the same time?

Comment: I'd like the record data and also what's returned when you call `sobjects/<SObject>/describe` request. Say my Lead has a custom picklist and I need to populate an HTML form to allow the user to update the lead. The picklist translates to a select tag, I have the value of the tag when I get the record data but I don't have the other possible options. The `describe` request gives me this information but it requires a separate API call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the standard APIs, it's not possible to retrieve record data and metadata in a single call.

You could, however, write an [Apex REST Method](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_methods.htm) to accept an SObject type and record ID and return both data and metadata. This might be viable if you're building an app to install into your customers' orgs.

Comment: Apex methods are Organisation-specific though, right? If I have users from say 3 Organisations, does each Org have to create their own Apex method for my app?

Comment: That's correct, but you can package an Apex method into an app (unmanaged/managed package). If your app is 'API only', with nothing to install into the org, then it's just not possible.